# Mail Reversing (Opposite of Forwarding)

Tags: email

I know mail can be forwarded, e.g. mail I receive will be sent to another account. However, can the reverse be true? That mail can be sent out and be delivered to another account before being sent to it's intended address.

For instance:

Guy #1 sends an e-mail to Guy #2
Guy #2 gets the e-mail, and passes it on to Guy #3 as well; mail forwarded.
Guy #2 sends and e-mail to Guy #1
Guy #3 receives the e-mail on its way out.

If this is possible, how would I go about this on an Exhange server 2007? And what would this be called anyways? It can't be mail reversing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest fix I can imagine is to enable auto backup of mail messages (default is a month, I believe), that would preserve the sent mail you're after.  (Chews through server disc space, of course)

Or set up another mailbox for each user to hold a copy of outgoing mail.  Exchange does those two, but for anything less kludgy, I think you're looking at some larger-scale content-management software.

Comment: How would one set up Exhange server to hold a copy of outgoing mail? That would be almost perfect, since that's what we do to store incoming mail as well.

Comment: It looks like the easiest way to set this up now with 2007 is transport rules.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to spy anyone?

Are you looking for BCC (blind carbon copy)?

Some MTA's (mail transfer agent's) do have this functionality, you just adds the mail address(es) that incoming/outgoing mails should be bcc'd to. I don't know if Exchange 2007 has it.

Comment: Well, yes and no. I'm the admin for a small business, we need to have all the e-mails in another account in case somebody leaves. So far we have all the incoming mails sent to a new account, but none of the sent mails. Users shouldn't have to enter bcc every time, otherwise it won't happen. Especially if they're planning on leaving.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a carbon copy. All that needs to be done is that Guy#2 puts Guy#3's e-mail address in the cc: field (or the bcc: field if he doesn't want Guy#1 to know), and Guy#3 will receive a copy.

Comment: Correct, though it needs to be without the user knowing. Maybe an automatic CC or BCC or something? I'm not sure if that's possible either.